# Flutter: How to change the state from inside a child widget of AnimatedSwitcher

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a screen in flutter that shows a question and displays an array of possible answers as buttons. The questions and answers are inside an AnimatedSwitcher widget, so once an answer button is clicked, the next question and answers should be displayed. Unfortunately, the AnimatedSwitcher widget only works when the button is outside its child widget. This is not the behaviour is want, since I want the answer and buttons to both be part of the animation.

Is there a way to do this or possibly a better widget to use? I'd be thankful for your help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int index = 0;

final widgets = [
  QuestionWidget(
      question:
          Question("What is your favorite color?", ["red", "blue", "green"]),
      key: const Key('1')),
  QuestionWidget(
      question: Question("How do you do today?", ["great", "not so well"]),
      key: const Key('2')),
  QuestionWidget(
      question: Question("Do you like Flutter", ["yes", "no"]),
      key: const Key('3')),
];

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: size.width * 0.7,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        transitionBuilder: (child, animation) =>
                            SlideTransition(
                                position: Tween<Offset>(
                                        begin: const Offset(0.0, -1.0),
                                        end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                                    .animate(animation),
                                child: FadeTransition(
                                    opacity: animation, child: child)),
                        child: widgets[index]),
                  ],
                ))));
  }
}

class QuestionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Question question;

  const QuestionWidget({
    required this.question,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuestionWidget> createState() => _QuestionWidgetState();
}

class _QuestionWidgetState extends State<QuestionWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(
        widget.question.questionText,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
        ),
      ),
      Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        spacing: 5.0,
        children: [
          for (var i in widget.question.answers)
            ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(i.toString()),
                onPressed: () {
                  final isLastIndex = index == widgets.length - 1;

                  setState(() => index = isLastIndex ? 0 : index + 1);
                })
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class Question {
  String questionText;
  List<String> answers;

  Question(this.questionText, this.answers);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing mutable state in global variables is not a valid approach in Flutter.

One of the main rules in Flutter developement is: state goes *down*, events go *up*.

In your case, it seems that the `Test` widget should be responsible for defining the index of the current question, so you need to make it a part of its `State`. The `Question` widget shouldn't care about what to do when the right answer is selected, it should only know how to detect such a event and who to notify about it.

Putting it all together:

1. `Test` should store the current question index
2. `Test` should select which `Question` to display at the given moment
3. `Question` should notify `Test` when the right answer is selected
4. `Test` should change the current index in response to the event above.

In your case, notifying about the event can be nothing more than just calling a callback provided in a constructor argument.

In code:

```dart
class TestState extends State<Test> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    QuestionWidget(
      key: Key(index.toString()),
      question: questions[index],
      onCorrectAnswer: () => setState(() => index++)),
    ),
    ...
  }
}

class QuestionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() onCorrectAnswer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => onCorrectAnswer(),
    ),
    ...
  }
}
```

I highly recommend reading [Flutter docs' take on state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot :) I posted my final code in an answer below since I made some other changes.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [mfkw1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72883472/11717159), I came up with this solution. I struggled a little with this which was because I did not see that the `QuestionWidget` was turned into a `StatelessWidget`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  int index = 0;

  next() {
    final isLastIndex = index == 2;
    setState(() => index = isLastIndex ? 0 : index + 1);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final widgets = [
      QuestionWidget(
          question: Question(
              "What is your favorite color?", ["red", "blue", "green"]),
          key: const Key("1"),
          onAnswer: () => next()),
      QuestionWidget(
          question: Question("How do you do today?", ["great", "not so well"]),
          key: const Key("2"),
          onAnswer: () => next()),
      QuestionWidget(
          question: Question("Do you like Flutter?", ["yes", "no"]),
          key: const Key("3"),
          onAnswer: () => next()),
    ];
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: size.width * 0.7,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    AnimatedSwitcher(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        transitionBuilder: (child, animation) =>
                            SlideTransition(
                                position: Tween<Offset>(
                                        begin: const Offset(0.0, -1.0),
                                        end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                                    .animate(animation),
                                child: FadeTransition(
                                    opacity: animation, child: child)),
                        child: widgets[index]),
                  ],
                ))));
  }
}

class QuestionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Question question;
  final Function() onAnswer;

  const QuestionWidget({
    required this.question,
    required this.onAnswer,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(
        question.questionText,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
        ),
      ),
      Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        spacing: 5.0,
        children: [
          for (var i in question.answers)
            ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(i.toString()),
                onPressed: () {
                  onAnswer();
                })
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class Question {
  String questionText;
  List<String> answers;

  Question(this.questionText, this.answers);
}
```